# Simple Carousel but target specific slide with when a certian link is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have created a simple carousel from looking at various tutorials on the web.

The carasol works but what i need to happen is if someone clicks link one it shows slide one, and of someone clicks slide 2 it shows slide 2 and so on.

I have given each link a unique class thinking i might be able to target the class name:

```
<a id="show-panel" class="cl_one" href="/link.html">Content 1</a> 
<a id="show-panel" class="cl_two" href="/link.html">Content 2</a>  
<a id="show-panel" class="cl_three" href="/link.html">Content 3</a>
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
$(".cl_one").click(function() {
        offset="0";                          
});
```

but it did not work as the vairable was only in that function

The above is based offset var on the post below but this did not work either

this one worked:

```
var left_value = item_width * (-1) * 1;
```

so did this one:

```
var left_value = item_width * (-1) * 2;
```

but this one went to a blank slide and broke the carasol:

```
var left_value = item_width * (-1) * 3;
```

**CODE:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZkeJf/4/

Note sure how to achieve what i need so any help / pointers would be great

I have added the light box to the code so it gives more of a picture of what i am trying to achive.

i also need to figure out how to stop the links going to the page (this is for non JS users)

Comment: To stop the links you can set the href='#' an empty id tag. Or add an onclick attribute i.e. `<a onclick="return false" href="whatever.com">link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this carousel http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ and after that use *offset* parameter to initiate from the second slide.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        offset:2
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank for your comment, i would like to try and achive this with the code i have already, rather then use a plug in. thanks alot though. Sluap

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use hash variables. Then you can do something like this

```
switch(window.location.hash)
{
case 'one': 
default:
  offset=1;
  break;
case 'two':
  offset=2
  break;
case 'three':
  offset =3;
  break;
}
var left_value = item_width * (-1) * offset;
```

This way you instantiate the default value based on your hash parameter.

Comment: thank you very mucy for you comment, but i could not get this to work, the brief has changed slightly explained above